# SettingsPane, SliderEditor (OptionEditor) changing values after creation

Tags: javafx, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

Is it possible to adjust values of an OptionEditor child class after creation?

I am using the SliderEditor code from the example http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/notes/ to create a SliderEditor.

```
public class SliderOption extends OptionBase<Number> {

private final int min;
private final int max;

public SliderOption(Node graphic, String caption, String description, String category, IntegerProperty value,
                    boolean isEditable, int min, int max) {
    super(graphic, caption, description, category, (Property<Number>) value, isEditable);
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

@Override
public Property<Number> valueProperty() {
    return value;
}

@Override
public Optional<Function<Option<Number>, OptionEditor<Number>>> editorFactoryProperty() {
    return Optional.of(option -> new SliderEditor(option, min, max));
}

public class SliderEditor implements OptionEditor<Number> {

    private final Slider slider;

    public SliderEditor(Option<Number> option, int min, int max) {
        slider = new Slider(min, max, option.valueProperty().getValue().doubleValue());
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(1);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(0);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        valueProperty().bindBidirectional(option.valueProperty());
    }

    @Override
    public Node getEditor() {
        return slider;
    }

    @Override
    public Number getValue() {
        return slider.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Number value) {
        slider.setValue(value.doubleValue());
    }

    @Override
    public final Property<Number> valueProperty() {
        return (Property<Number>) slider.valueProperty();
    }
  }

}
```

Creating the settingsPane and slider:

```
    SettingsPane settingsPane  = new SettingsPane();
    settingsPane.setSearchBoxVisible(false);
    final Option<Number> sliderOption = new SliderOption(MaterialDesignIcon.PERSON.graphic(),
            "Text", "Set the text size", null,settings.getProperty() , true, 0, 10);
    settingsPane.getOptions().addAll(sliderOption, new DefaultOption(Option.SEPARATOR));
```

Works great but in a buttonEvent i would like to disable the slider:

```
     Slider slider = (Slider)settingsPane.getOptionEditorFactory().call(sliderOption).getEditor();
     slider.setDisable(true);
     slider.setValue(10);
```

Disable does nothing, also tried setmax/setshowticklabels none work except setvalues it works like a charm. It seems like i cannot modify the slider except its value. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because `setDisable` is not called on the original `Slider` but on a new instance which is created by the factory method:

```
  @Override
    public Optional<Function<Option<Number>, OptionEditor<Number>>> editorFactoryProperty() {
         return Optional.of(option -> new SliderEditor(option, min, max, slider));
    }
```

So instead of creating a new instance each time, you have to return the original instance:

```
  public  class SliderOption extends OptionBase<Number> {

        private final SliderEditor sliderEditor;

        public SliderOption(Node graphic, String caption, String description, String category, IntegerProperty value,
                            boolean isEditable, int min, int max) {
            super(graphic, caption, description, category, value, isEditable);

            sliderEditor = new SliderEditor(this, min, max);
        }

        @Override
        public Property<Number> valueProperty() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<Function<Option<Number>, OptionEditor<Number>>> editorFactoryProperty() {
            // return Optional.of(option -> new SliderEditor(option, min, max, slider));
            return Optional.of(option -> sliderEditor);
        }
    }
```

> Disable does nothing, also tried setmax/setshowticklabels none work except setvalues it works like a charm.

setValue works because the valueProperty of the new `Slider` instance is bound bidirectional to the valueProperty of the existing `Option` instance, which is bound to the original `Slider` as well.